# Apache, url rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following `.htaccess` file inside my root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On


<If "%{SERVER_NAME} = 'example.com'">

# The actual condition is really long one so I replaced it for illustration.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|Blackberry|Android) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z-]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME}/?title=%1 [L]

</If>

<Else>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z-]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME}/?title=%1 [L]

DirectoryIndex /m/index.htm /m/index.php /m/index.html

</Else>
```

So as you can see its a pretty much simple way to redirect users of mobile devices to `m.example.com` and if that is the case I change the `DirectoryIndex`, few notes:

- The reason I duplicate the same `RewriteCond/RewriteRule` is because I can't use them outside `<If>/<Else>` blocks.
- The way I redirect(`if/else`) is **not the question** and I'm pretty sure not the best way, but if anyone have suggestions I'm all ears.

**The problem:**

If I access `example.com/Article-Name` on **desktop browser** there will be internal redirection to: `example.com/?title=articleName` **but** I won't see `example.com/?title=articleName` at my url bar **as expected.**

**The exception:**

If I access `m.example.com/Article-Name` my url bar is now `m.example.com/?title=articleName`.

I was expecting the same behavior as the desktop (internal redirection not redirection I can see on my url bar), I'm pretty sure its because the **DirectoryIndex** but I don't how to prove it or solve this issue, if anyone have a solution I will be very thankful.

Comment: `RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME}/?title=%1 [L]` this is really really really bad for internal redirects, what happens in your case is that the moment it changes from domain.com to m.domain.com it is not longer a internal redirect as it changed the hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you're feeding it with an URL that is not the same as the current URL then, what happens is that it ignores the internal and make it an external redirect.

**Another very important thing is that you forgot `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` to match against the mobile browsers.**

Here is an idea to resolve your issue:

```
RewriteEngine On

# First we verify if its a mobile device and
# if its not already on the mobile subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|Blackberry|Android) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# here we deal with all the internal redirects for
# the mobile subdomain
RewriteRule ^m/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /m/index.php?title=$1 [L]

# here we deal with the normal website
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: the reason I was using `DirectoryIndex` is because `m.example.com` points to the same ip as `example.com`, if I redirect the users to the `m` folder it will be visible on the url bar, do you think there is another variation where it will invisible?

Comment: about I edited my question about the HTTP_USER_AGENT.

Comment: @AvielFadida the above `.htaccess` is currently invisible to the user, as it does a internal redirect only when its on the mobile subdomain.

Comment: @AvielFadida so it worked fine? If so glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing internal redirects, if you want to redirect to a new URL use external ones

Replace `[L]` with `[L,R=302]`

or `301` if you want the result to be cached

Comment: If you give an internal redirect an external URL with different domain it will threat it as `R`.